# Store href form TD to value, add attr url with stored href to separate TD

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is copy the href attr from one TD to another TD within the same TR.

```
jQuery('.course-number a').each(function () {
    var lnk = jQuery('this').attr('href');
    jQuery(this).sibling('.course-name').attr('href', lnk);
});

<table>
<tr id="post" class="post-337">
<td class="course-number">
    <a href="http://newimageregistration.com/nic-tempsite/courses/action-for-actors/">ACON-6</a>
</td>
</tr>
<td class="course-name">
    ACTION FOR ACTORS   </td>
</table>
```

Sounds straight forward, but can't find the answer. Is this a limitation on table structure or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems, 1) it should be `this`, not `'this'`, 2) `course-name` is a sibling of the parent of the `course-number a` element, 3) It is `siblings()` not `sibling()`

```js
jQuery('.course-number a').each(function() {
  var lnk = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.course-name').attr('href', lnk);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="post" class="post-337">
    <td class="course-number">
      <a href="http://newimageregistration.com/nic-tempsite/courses/action-for-actors/">ACON-6</a>
    </td>
    <td class="course-name">
      ACTION FOR ACTORS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

But if you want to make the contents of the second element like a anchor, then you will have to

```js
jQuery('.course-number a').each(function() {
  var lnk = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.course-name').wrapInner('<a href="' + lnk + '"/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="post" class="post-337">
    <td class="course-number">
      <a href="http://newimageregistration.com/nic-tempsite/courses/action-for-actors/">ACON-6</a>
    </td>
    <td class="course-name">
      ACTION FOR ACTORS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wrapInner! Brilliant. Much obliged.